# Run SSh from php or bach and Handler keyboard-interactive authentication

Tags: php, python, batch-file, ssh, phpseclib

i'm trying to make connect to ssh host who have keyboard-interactive(auth) after put the username, it's generate key and display it, then it's should encrypt and send again to success login.

i found the idea writen in python but i can't run it in windows, .

http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/26

my php source ssh.php :

```
$ssh = new phpseclib\Net\SSH2('169.254.201.230');
$ssh->login('Fortimanager_Access');
print $ssh->read();
```

it's say :

> PHP Notice:  Operation disallowed prior to login() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cli\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\Net\SSH2.php on line 2804

i try another way using putty command line (plink.exe)

system("C:\plink.exe" Fortimanager_Access@127.0.0.1 >z && type z && type z >> z.txt");

but it's not saving the log wish contain the generated string from keyboard-interactive.

example from putty  :

> login as: Fortimanager_Access
>
> Using keyboard-interactive authentication. -840056459
>
> Access denied
>
> Using keyboard-interactive authentication. -1378285763
>
> AK1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAmWT0TKGMI23Iq4Q9P42z0PwpYBQ=

it would be good if i can run bat from php in midlle of plink

I've spent the past couple of days going through trying to figure this out, and this is the closest that I've been able to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was cross-posted at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1146. Quoting the answer:

> That's not currently possible with phpseclib. Right now phpseclib (as elaborated at http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html#keyboard) supports two methods for dealing with keyboard-interactive authentication.
>
> 1. Order based. eg. if you have two parameters (after the username) each of them are passed to the keyboard-interactive prompt in the order that they appear in the function call.
> 2. Context based. eg. you tell phpseclib what should be sent when a known prompt is encountered.
>
> You're talking about dynamic prompt's and adjusting the response based on the prompt. It'd require a decent amount of work to make phpseclib do that. It's a good idea and I'll add it to my list of changes to make for 3.0 when I get around to doing revamping SSH but that's a ways away.